# How to query an inverse ManyToMany relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm

*Disclaimer: I am new to Laravel but have experience with other MVC frameworks such as Django*

I have 3 main tables and two many to many tables.

A user can be part of a client and a department, and for each client a user is a part of, they have a rank. A client can also have many departments, but a department can only be part of one client.

Roughly the many to many (pivot?) tables look like this:

```
client_users

- user_id
- client_id
- rank_id
```

---

```
department_users

- department_id
- user_id
```

So in Laravel I have my client model:

```
class Client extends Model
{
    /**
    * Columns:
    * @property name = varchar(255)
    **/

    protected $table = 'clients';

    // Relationships
    public function departments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Grouping\Department');
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Grouping\ClientUser');
    }
}

class ClientUser extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'client_users';
}
```

The problem with this is that when I do `$client->users()->get()` it returns the many to many data and not the actual users. I want it to return a list of users, not a list of data that links the users.

I have looked at the documentation and cannot figure out how to do this. I have to somehow through the many to many, return the users and not the many to many relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to define the pivots as a separate model. You can, but you don't have to.

As long as you use the naming conventions, Laravel will sort out which pivot to use.

What you're looking for is something like this (I don't know your namespaces):

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Grouping\Department::class); // 1:n
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Grouping\User::class, 'client_users'); // will look for pivot client_users
    }
}


class Department extends Model
{
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Grouping\Client::class); // inverse 1:n
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Grouping\User::class, 'department_users'); // will look for pivot department_users
    }
}


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Grouping\Client::class, 'client_users'); // will look for pivot client_users
    }


    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Grouping\Department::class, 'department_users'); // will look for pivot department_users
    }
}
```

Now using

```
$client->users;
```

Will return a collection of User objects.

If you need info from the pivot (for example: rank_id), you can do like this:

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Grouping\User::class)
            ->withPivot('rank_id');
    }
```

---

Edit:

Added 2nd param in `->belongsToMany()` to define the pivot table

Comment: Argh, completely went over my head that Client to User is also just a many to many. Anyway it still does not work because Laravel looks for `client_user` and not `client_users`. Anyway to change that?

Comment: Yes, see edit. You can use the 2nd param for that. Optionally you can use the 3rd and 4th to define the keys, but I don't think you need them.